# How to extract the calculated expected frequencies in a higher-dimensional mosaicplot in R

Tags: r, plot, contingency

After producing a table with three-variables as in:

```
salary <- array(
  c(38, 12, 102, 141, 12, 9, 136, 383),
  dim=c(2, 2, 2),
  dimnames=list(exposure = c("exposed", "not"),
                disease = c("case", "control"),
                salary = c("<1000", ">=1000"))
) 

salary
, , salary = <1000

         disease
exposure  case control
  exposed   38     102
  not       12     141

, , salary = >=1000

         disease
exposure  case control
  exposed   12     136
  not        9     383
```

the `vcd` package allows the creation of a mosaic plot like this:

```
mosaic(salary, shade = T)
```

[image]

in which the surface area is proportional to the counts in the cell, and the color corresponds to the standardized Pearson's residuals.

The question is **how to calculate and extract the expected counts?**

I know that I can produce the margins like this:

```
addmargins(salary)
, , salary = <1000

         disease
exposure  case control Sum
  exposed   38     102 140
  not       12     141 153
  Sum       50     243 293

, , salary = >=1000

         disease
exposure  case control Sum
  exposed   12     136 148
  not        9     383 392
  Sum       21     519 540

, , salary = Sum

         disease
exposure  case control Sum
  exposed   50     238 288
  not       21     524 545
  Sum       71     762 833
```

and if it were a 2 x 2 contingency table I would use `chisq.test(x)$expected` to see the expected values, but I don't know how to go about it in a 3-way contingency table.

Comment: The `chisq.test` from the `stats` package can be run on a nxn contingency table, where x is a numeric matrix.  See `?chisq.test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a designated argument to compute (and visualize) expected values using the `type = "expected"` option.

```
mos_exp <- mosaic(salary, type = "expected")

mos_exp

#>                 disease       case    control
#> exposure salary                              
#> exposed  <1000            8.634326  92.666994
#>          >=1000          15.913093 170.785587
#> not      <1000           16.339263 175.359416
#>          >=1000          30.113318 323.188003
```